# How do I add original amount of oldest transaction in an aggregate function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to find out how to include the original amount of the first transaction (oldest by Posted Date) to an aggregate query.

The following finds reversed transactions ..

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
    [Account], [Voucher],
    [DocumentDate],
    SUM([Amount])   
FROM            
    MyTable 
WHERE           
    [Account] = 'abc'
GROUP BY
    [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate]
HAVING          
    SUM([Amount]) = 0
```

How would I include the amount in the results for the transaction with the oldest posted date for each record?

For example, using the following:

```
Account   Voucher   DocumentDate   PostedDate   Amount
---------------------------------------------------------
abc         1       01/01/2018     08/01/2018    100.00
abc         1       01/01/2018     15/01/2018   -100.00
```

The expected result would be:

```
Account   Voucher   DocumentDate   OriginalAmount   Sum(Amount)   Records
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc          1      01/01/2018        100.00           0.00          2
```

Comment: Is OriginalAmount=-100 ???

Comment: Hi Saravanatn, The original amount would be 100, as the oldest Posted Date for the 2 transactions is 08/01/2018.  The second transaction on 15/01/2018 for -100 is the reversal.  (Date format = DD/MM/YYYY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is using a cte with [`first_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql), `sum...over` and `count...over`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Account char(3),
    Voucher int,
    DocumentDate date,
    PostedDate date,
    Amount numeric(5,2)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('abc', 1, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-08', 100),
('abc', 1, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-15', -100)
```

The cte:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  [Account], 
            [Voucher],
            [DocumentDate],
            FIRST_VALUE(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate] ORDER BY PostedDate) AS OriginalAmount,
            SUM([Amount]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate]) AS [Sum(Amount)],
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate]) Records
    FROM            
        @T 
    WHERE           
        [Account] = 'abc'
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE [Sum(Amount)] = 0
```

Results:

```
Account     Voucher     DocumentDate            OriginalAmount  Sum(Amount)     Records
abc         1           01.01.2018 00:00:00     100,00          0,00            2
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/SVI12864)

Comment: Hi Zohar, that's great I've got it working on one server, much appreciated for  your help.  I also have SQL 2009 with it doesn't work on (due to FIRST_VALUE), so I'll check the other solution also :)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 1):

It seems straightforward ... am I missing something?

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [Account], 
        [Voucher],
        [DocumentDate],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Account],[Voucher] ORDER BY [DocumentDate]) RN,
        [Amount]
    FROM            
        MyTable 
    WHERE           
        [Account] = 'abc'
)
SELECT 
        [Account], 
        [Voucher],
        [DocumentDate],
        max(case when RN = 1 THEN [Amount] else null end) OriginalAmount,
        sum([Amount]) SUM_Amount,
        count(*) Records
from cte
GROUP BY
    [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate]
HAVING          
    SUM([Amount]) = 0
```

Comment: Yes, you are missing the `partition by` clause in your `row_number`. as your query is written now, only one record will get the value `1` for it's `RN`. You should add `partition by [Account], [Voucher], [DocumentDate]` to your over clause.

Comment: @ZoharPeled ... yes you are right. Thanks. I don't think the document date is necessary. It depends on the definition of natural key in this context/

Comment: It's a part of the original group by, so I guess it's necessary. your `order by` should be on `PostedDate`.

Comment: Thanks again Zohar for the first solution and commenting on Ildanny's suggestion.  Ildanny, thanks to you also as I needed an alternative that works on SQL 2009, which yours does with the modifications suggested. :)